# kinect choices for object detection

Tags: kinect

i'm involved in object detection problem using kinect but i'm really feeling lost i need some help in the following:

1-Should i use kinect SDK or open source tools ? what is the performance gain if certain choice was selected ?

2-Should i use open CV for programming  or not ? what is the performance gain if certain choice was selected ?

3-In what language should i program given that i know little about C++ and no nothing about C# but have time to learn ?

Please help.

Comment: Kinect isn't really meant for object detection...

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK The Kinect SDK currently doesn't support object detection out of the box.

I recommend having a look at the [Point Clouds Library(PCL)](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/).

[image: PCL features]

It's an opensource c++ library for computer vision, but mainly focusing on 3d point cloud data. It has a great and very active community and you will probably find the latest techniques in 3d computer vision implemented in PCL